# How to check the structs(fields) stored in the vector using gtest constructs?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, testing, googletest

I want to check the validity of the structs stored in the container using *gtest*. One way of doing it is retrieving the struct and comparing with the expected value. Is there a better way other than this using *gtest* constructs.

```
auto receivedflexmessages = m_pugwintegration->getFlexMessages();
EXPECT_EQ(m_expectedflexmessages.size(), receivedflexmessages.size()) << "Mismatch in the received messages";

for (auto i = 0; i < receivedflexmessages.size(); i++)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(m_expectedflexmessages[i].m_extId, receivedflexmessages[i].m_extId) << i << "Mismatch in extId";
    EXPECT_EQ(m_expectedflexmessages[i].m_handle, receivedflexmessages[i].m_handle) << i << "Mismatch in handle";
    EXPECT_EQ(m_expectedflexmessages[i].m_payloadLength, receivedflexmessages[i].m_payloadLength) << i << "Mismatch in payloadlength";

    if (m_expectedflexmessages[i].m_payloadLength == receivedflexmessages[i].m_payloadLength)
    {
        for (auto j = 0; j < m_expectedflexmessages[i].m_payloadLength; ++j)
        {
            EXPECT_EQ(m_expectedflexmessages[i].m_pPayload[j], receivedflexmessages[i].m_pPayload[j]) << "Payload expected and received differ at index " << j;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, equality operator.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways - both with use of [gtest Container matchers](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#matching-containers):

1. `::testing::ContainerEq` with equality operator defined for container `value_type`

See:

```
using namespace ::testing;
EXPECT_THAT(receivedflexmessages, ContainerEq(m_expectedflexmessages));

// that is - just 1 line not counting operator == () 
// for decltype(m_expectedflexmessages)::value_type
```

2. `::testing::ElementsAreArray` and build vector of matchers on a top of `m_expectedflexmessages`

```
using namespace ::testing;
using ElementType = decltype(receivedflexmessages)::value_type;
std::vector<Matcher<ElementType >> m_expectedflexmessagesMatchers;

for (auto&& expectedMessage : m_expectedflexmessages)
{
    m_expectedflexmessagesMatchers.push_back(AllOf(
        Field(&ElementType::m_extId, expectedMessage.m_extId),
        Field(&ElementType::m_handle, expectedMessage.m_handle),
        Field(&ElementType::m_payloadLength, expectedMessage.m_payloadLength),
        Field(&ElementType::m_pPayload, ElementsAreArray(expectedMessage.m_pPayload, expectedMessage.m_payloadLength)));
}
EXPECT_THAT(receivedflexmessages, ElementsAreArray(m_expectedflexmessagesMatchers));
```

---

I do not advice to use the shortest form `EXPECT_EQ(m_expectedflexmessages, receivedflexmessages)` (assuming you have operator == for ElementType) - because you will lost information of first non-matching element index (and size) when test fails. With above mentioned matchers - this information will be present on the screen.

Additionally you might want to implement `PrintTo(const ElementType&, std::ostream* os) { ... }` to have even better presentation what fails to compare